Azure text to speech SDK return SSL parsing error
using node sdk of microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk
Speech synthesis canceled, Status(StatusCode="FailedPrecondition", Detail="SSML parsing error: 0x8004801c - Wanted data exists  websocket error code: 1007Did you set the speech resource key and region values?

running the same script, sometimes able to return audio file and sometimes doesn't
Here is sample of ssml:
<speak xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xmlns:mstts="http://www.w3.org/2001/mstts" xmlns:emo="http://www.w3.org/2009/10/emotionml" version="1.0" xml:lang="en-US">
<voice name="en-US-JennyNeural">   
<mstts:express-as style="cheerful">   
<mstts:silence type="Tailing-exact" value="80ms" />   
<prosody pitch="+2.00%" rate="1.02" volume="75"><say-as interpret-as="string" format="string" detail="string">wait a lever</say-as></prosody>   
</mstts:express-as>   
</voice></speak>

copying the exact same ssml via debugger output then pasting to https://speech.microsoft.com/portal/ audio content creation as ssml works fine, but running it via script returns above error (most of the time)
It only started happening last few days; any idea why? I'm on the free-tier plan (checked that my quota is not exceeded)

This was an ongoing issue which many customers had raised for a week ago.
.
Cause:
There is a code bug which corrupt our engine when user sending refresh lexicon signal. All request with lexicon tag after it will failed to load lexicon files
.
Current Status of the fix:
We have fixed the issue on SouthEastAsia, East US, East US 2 and West Europe. The fix is not yet deployed to all regions.
May I know which region is your Speech resource deployed to ?
Could you please test this again in any of the above regions and let me know if you are still encountering this issue ?
Reference
